# How to find the non-maximum nor minimum value (note: NOT middle value)

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

test case [3,1,2,4]

```
class Solution:
    def findNonMinOrMax(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        lst = []

        for n in range(100):
            numbers = input(nums)
            lst.append(numbers)
            a = int()
            if a != max() in lst and a != min() in lst:
                print(a)
```

I was expecting [2,1]
it gave me syntax error on this "If a != max() in lst and a != min() in lst:"

Comment: Please share the error.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of what you want because the title and the test case do not coincide:

1. Get a list without the minimum and maximum values.
2. Get a list without the first and last values.

Here, I'm providing solutions for both. It is the first time that I answer a question, so I hope it is right.

### Get a list without the minimum and maximum values

You may use NumPy library, which is very useful to work with arrays, to find the minimum and maximum values. Then, you can create a new list that doesn't contain such minimum and maximum values.

The code would be:

```
import numpy as np

def findNonMinOrMax(nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    # Conver the list to a numpy array
    nums = np.asarray(nums)

    # Get the minimum and maximum values of the array
    max_value = nums.max()
    min_value = nums.min()

    # Create a list with only the values that are different to min_value and max_value
    lst = [number for number in nums if number != max_value and number != min_value]
    
    # Return the list
    return lst
```

An example of use would be:

```
>>> findNonMinOrMax([3,1,2,4])
>>> [3, 2]
```

The result is [3, 2] as the minimum value is 1 and the maximum is 4.

### Get a list without the first and last values

You can use slicers to remove the first and last values. When you are working with lists, you may get a part of it by using the syntaxis `list_variable[start:end]`. If end is -1, you remove the last element, and if start is 1, you remove the first element.

The code would be:

```
def findNonMinOrMax(nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    return nums[1:-1]
```

An example of use would be:

```
>>> findNonMinOrMax([3,1,2,4])
>>> [1, 2]
```